# Filter column for does not contain

Tags: excel, powershell, xlsx, xls

I am trying to delete the rows in a column of a xls file that does not contain a certain number as such:

```
before:
a | b | c
1   2   3
1   3   5
2   6   4
1   2   5

after:
a | b | c
2   6   4
```

I've previously looked for a solution, but all the solutions I saw were for csv files.

The solution I've attempted is this:

```
$needle = '1'
$caseSensitive = 'false'

$column = $excel.Range('M').EntireColumn.Cells

$deleteRange = $null

$found = $column.Find($needle, [type]::Missing, [type]::Missing, [type]::Missing, [type]::Missing, [type]::Missing, $caseSensitive)
$firstAddress = $found.Address()
if (-not $found) {
    do {
        if ($deleteRange) {
            $deleteRange = $excel.Application.Union($deleteRange, $found.EntireRow.Cells)
        } else {
            $deleteRange = $found.EntireRow.Cells
        }
        $found = $column.FindNext($found)
    } while ($found -and ($found.Address() -ne $firstAddress))
}
```

but this does not filter the column as I thought.

Comment: Would converting the xls to a csv be an option for you?

Comment: For now: no, but I will see if a csv is an acceptable format

Comment: Your sample data is hardly representative of the many possible conditions that could occur. All you have to do is autofilter field 1 for <>2 and delete what's visible to accomplish your goal.